# Ubuntu VM: why is it still there after remove?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

Due to some problems on my VM on which Ubuntu 12.04 LTS was running, I removed the entire VirtualBox system and I reinstalled a new one.
After installation, I was surprised to see that my former Ubuntu VM is still there with all the data I left inside !
Can someone explain me why this happened ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you still have all your virtual machines and their settings after removal and reinstallation of the Virtual Box application is a strictly separated storage of the actual application, and user created data.

From Virtual Box >= 4.0 all files created by any user will be stored in a subdirectory in our HOME directory (see [Virtual Box manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch10.html#vboxconfigdata)):

1. **Global settings**

   From 4.3. global configuration settings for your Virtual Box environment are stored in `~/.config/VirtualBox/`. If we had upgraded from a version < 4.3 of Virtual Box the directory `~/.VirtualBox` will still be used instead. It is also the location where registered VMs are stored in an `.XML` file.
2. **Virtual machines**

   All virtual machines and their settings are stored in an own directory, per default in `~/Virtual Box VMs/<Name of VM>/`. Old machines from previous releases of Virtual Box will still reside in the `~/.VirtualBox/Machines` for compatibility reasosn.

To delete virtual machines we will therefore have to unregister any machine and then also delete the machine's hard disk(s) and settings. This can easily be done from the [Virtual Box Virtual Media Manager](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch05.html#vdis).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the newer virtualbox automatically detects the previously created Virtual Machine and shows it on the Virtual Machines list.

Comment: Thank you, but I removed FIRST: my Ubuntu VM. THEN, I downloaded VirtualBox 4.3.13  and installed it (while I was running 4.3.10 just before). So how come everything is back now ? Is not it strange ?

Comment: I think you selected Remove only option while removing the VM. But the file (.vdi) still exists in the Hard-disk.

Comment: Yes, it was there because when I installed the new VB it said something like this : "do you want to import existing VM ..." (I do not remember exactly what was the message).

Comment: The created virtual machine file (.vdi) was still exists in your HDD which inturn makes the new VB to prompt a message(import existing VM's) at the startup.